# How to join multiple repositories

Tags: magento2.3, join, repositories

Suppose if I want to join product repository and orderItem repository, then how can do that?

There is way to join multiple collections (methods like join, joinRight, joinLeft, ...), how to do same with repositories?

Comment: Anshu, actually what you want to achieve.Can you please  describe in details

Comment: @AmitBera I just want to know how I can join multiple repositories. Like collection has the join method to join multiple collection, how can I do the same with repositories.